# Compatibility of ClojureScript & Cloud Firestore for Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, clojurescript

TLDR; Does ClojureScript retain the realtime functionality of Cloud Firestore? If so, how would I implement it using the firebase API?

I am building the front end for my serverless web application. I already have implemented some complex cloud functions that perform writes to Cloud Firestore (Golang).

I want to use ClojureScript & the Firebase API to create my Front End. I worry that I will not be able to retain the realtime functionality of Firestore reads.

In particular, when an object is viewed in my front end, I would trigger an update method on that object. My hope is that via the magic of Firestore/Firebase, when the object has changed, it would also do so in the view of my web app.

I know ClojureScript compiles into JS, so I figure it must be possible. But I wanted to verify before committing to learning ClojureScript for my web app.

I have found a few Cljs libraries which implement firebase, but it seems most of them are not actively maintained or depreciated.

So is it possible? And how would I go about doing it? Is there a cljs design paradigm to follow? I would like to use re-frame and reagent

I have read the JS & Node.js documentation. Should I be using one over the other?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0

Using Cljs, when viewing object X, if X is updated in Firestore, the view of X shows the updated object. Without reloading the page or polling the DB.

Comment: In the future, I would like to use other Firebase features such as authentication, that is why I have asked about Firestore via Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore realtime update works by registering a callback function.
You can use any of your cljs functions for that.